# error SyntaxError: Unexpected token comando nodemon src/server.js --exec babel-node

Tags: reactjs, babel

Tengo un proyecto en MERN, el cual estoy migrando el backend desde otra computadora hacia la mía, pero al correr el servidor con el comando `nodemon src/server.js --exec babel-node` me muestra `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.
Quién me paso el proyecto le funcionaba correctamente todo y la verdad yo he probado de todo y no he resuelto con nada.
Adjunto imagen del error.
Si necesitan algo mas pueden pedirmelo, no tengo mucha experiencia creando preguntas en stackoverflow.
Saludos, espero que me ayuden y muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y adjunta tu `package.json`. Asegúrate de tener `@babel/runtime ^7.0.0`, todo parece indicar que se trata de [este error](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1205).

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo solucione. Al parecer el problema era yarn, instale todas las dependencias con npm y todo funciono a la perfeccion. No se por que yarn daba ese problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.